# Html 5 notification not working in Mobile browser

Tags: html, reactjs, android-notifications, html5-audio

i have implemented `HTML5 notification API` in my Reactjs application, it's working fine in my desktop,the notifications are coming. But when opening the site in my mobile phone,the notifications are not working.
How can i fix this Issue in my Reactjs application.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("permission" + window.Notification.permission);
    if (
      (window.Notification && Notification.permission !== "denied") ||
      (window.Notification && Notification.permission === "default")
    ) {
      Notification.requestPermission();
    }
  }, []);



 const showNotification = () => {
      const options = {
        label: "New notification",
        body: "notification body"),
        icon: icon,
        badge: icon,
      };
      const notification = new Notification(t("New "), options);
      setTimeout(() => {
        notification.close();
      }, 5 * 1000);
    };
```